# Docker container exibits different behavour when run automatically

Tags: python, docker

I have a basic Python Docker container that uses the O365 library to retrieve mail from Office365.

```
FROM python:3
ADD requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./main ./main
CMD [ "python", "./main/main.py"]
```

The first time you run this O365 library, you need to authorize it and it stores a `o365_token.txt` which it uses after that. That looks like this:

```
Visit the following url to give consent:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?resp....
Paste the authenticated url here:
```

This also happened on my new Docker so I logged in to it through Bash:

`docker run -it hvdveer/e2t-python bash`

But now when I manually run it, it just utilizes the existing token and it works without verification. Deleting the token files and authorizing it again also doesn't work. Why does it ask for authorization when I run it automatically, but not when run it manually? Are these different users? How to I fix this?

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you ran your script inside docker container which created a token file. Now you are able to access this token from outside your container. right?

Comment: You already generate `o365_token.txt`, why still need login, your question is not clear.

Comment: When I login manually it doesn't ask for authorization, but when I run it automatically (docker run) it does.

Comment: Where is that file?  Is this a long-running service, or do you repeatedly `sudo docker  run ...` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

The CMD is run from the root directory so it's looking for the token there. By changing the WORKDIR to the main of my program it now finds the token:

```
FROM python:3
ADD requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /main
ADD ./main .
CMD [ "python", "./main.py"]
```

The reason why running it from root by hand and creating a token in root didn't solve the problem, is because those changes aren't saved. Apparently every time you close the image it forgets everything. Live and learn.